# Solution of $\left|\frac{\sin Mx}{\sin x}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin NMx}{\sin Nx}\right|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking for the smallest solution of 
$$\left|\frac{\sin Mx}{\sin x}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin NMx}{\sin Nx}\right|$$
where $M < N - 1$ are integers and $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

By plotting both sides for different $N$ and $M$'s I noticed that the smallest solution is independent of $M$. In other words, for a given $N$ changing $M$ doesn't result in the change of the smallest solution. I can't figure out this independence.

For example, $\left|\frac{\sin Mx}{\sin x}\right| - \left|\frac{\sin NMx}{\sin Nx}\right|$ is plotted for $N = 7$ and different values of $M$ in the figure below.
[image: sd]

Comment: Can you show us a case for which the claim holds ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question is edited to do your favor.

Answer (score 1):

For integer $k$ we have $\sin(k\pi + x) = (-1)^{k}\sin(x) \implies |\sin(k\pi+x)| = |\sin(x)|$ so if $x = \frac{\pi}{N+1}$ it follows that $$|\sin(Nx)| = |\sin(x)|, ~~~|\sin(Mx)| = |\sin(MNx)|\implies \left|\frac{\sin(Mx)}{\sin(x)}\right| = \left|\frac{\sin(MNx)}{\sin(Nx)}\right|$$

Thus $x = \frac{\pi}{N+1}$ is a solution independent of $M$. I suspect this is the solution you have observed. Numerically one can check that this is the smallest positive solution for the first few values of $N$ if $M<N-1$ (I checked it for $N<20$), but proving this seems messy.

By symmetry and periodicy we also have the ($M$-independent) solutions $x = -\frac{\pi}{N+1}$, $x=0$, $x = k\pi$ and $x = k\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{N+1}$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: Thanks. How to find another solutions (beside the smallest one)?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Well, by symmetry and periodicy we have that $x = -\frac{\pi}{N+1}$, $x=0$, $x = \pi k$ and $x = \pi k \pm \frac{\pi}{N+1}$ are all solutions for any integer $k$.

Comment: Actually, I asked this question since I found that this is the solution of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372288/the-solution-of-min-x-max-1-leq-r-leq-n-left-frac-sin-rmx-sin-rx-rig). Would you mind checking that?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the absolute value and transform the difference $$f(N,M)=\frac{\sin Mx}{\sin x}- \frac{\sin NMx}{\sin Nx}$$
For example if $M=2$ and $N=7$ then I claim that: $$f(7,2)=2(\cos x - \cos 7x)$$

Generalize and this will give you the idea when the root is independent of M.

Comment: for $M = 2$ it is easy to compute $f$. How about $M > 2$?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi Generalize

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials might be helpful

Comment: The way this is presented it seems to suggest that $f(N,M) = M(\cos(x) - \cos(Nx))$ which is not true.

Comment: No, I suggest that there are some (small) values of M, where similar simplification can be done. In the general case, what the OP is asking to verify is not true.

Comment: @ivan Why what I am asking is not true?