# The solution of $\min_x \max_{1\leq r \leq N} \left|\frac{\sin rMx}{\sin rx}\right|$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

I am looking for the solution of

$$\min_x \max_{1\leq r \leq N} \left|\frac{\sin rMx}{ M \sin rx}\right|$$
where $M < N$ are integers and $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

For $M = 4, N = 6$, $f_{r,M}(x) =\left|\frac{\sin rMx}{ M \sin rx}\right|$ is plotted for different values of $r$ in the figure below. The maximum is plotted as well.

As it is shown the first intersection of $f_{1,M}(x)$ and $f_{N,M}(x)$ (the smallest positive $x$ for which $f_{1,M}(x) = f_{N,M}(x)$) is the solution of the optimization problem.

If this is true for all values of $N$ then the problem reduces to ${x}^\ast = \min\{x \in \mathbb{R}^+ | f_{1,M}(x) = f_{N,M}(x)\}$ that is claimed to be $x^\ast = \pi / N$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1372299/84247).
[image]

I also noticed that for a given $N$, changing $M$ doesn't change the smallest positive solution (the first intersection point).